# Battery Percentage can't exceed 58%

Tags: laptop, power-management, lenovo, battery

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on my Laptop. I have Lenovo G40-80 and the battery is absolutely new (I actually got it yesterday). However, it doesn't matter how much time the battery is charged, it never exceeds 59%.

[image]

I understood that this has something to do with "units battery". I don't know what this term means, and I got the following guidance how to solve it on Windows OS:

> 1. Please search under “settings” for “energy” and click “Change Battery settings”
> 2. Then click “change plan settings” and then “change advanced power settings”
> 3. Then click the tab for “Lenovo energy management” and then “Enable Lenovo energy management”
> 4. Under Battery the settings from “Optimized Battery Health” as shown below to “Maximum Battery Life”

Do you have any idea how to see solve this issue on Ubuntu?

Comment: *You can't under Ubuntu nor the BIOS:*.  However, the settings you have are set up for very long battery life, so not too bad neither...

Comment: so... what you actually say is that is can't be resolved?

Comment: This problem cannot be resolved under Ubuntu.  These are settings that were set under Windows and they need to be resolved under Windows.  **:-(**

Comment: What causes Ubuntu to define 'full charge' as 59%? It doesn't make sense. It is even a bug in Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you also have Windows installed? If so, does it have the same bug?

Comment: no. I have only LInux on this machine

Answer (score 2):

**The only way to fix this if your computer isn't a ThinkPad is to use Lenovo Power Management, which is only available on Windows, to change the battery threshold settings.**

This is caused by the charge threshold being set to 59% in the Lenovo Power Management application, which is, unfortunately, only available on Windows. This setting is contained in the computer's firmware, so it will persist across operating systems. There *is* a [utility](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tpacpi-bat) for Linux that can change the battery thresholds, but it's only compatible with ThinkPads.